# Why is var in same function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var wordlist = [ "A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD" ];

            for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                x.setAttribute("type", "button");
                x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this.id, wordlist[3])");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
        }

        function isTOF(v, word) {
            console.log(word);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that `console.log(word)` will show me "DDDD", but it says like this:

> wordlist is not defined

How can I make it run?

Comment: How can I edit my code?

Comment: Attach the handler using Javascript rather than an HTML attribute as in my answer there, and `wordlist` will be in scope of the listener function. (alternatively, make `wordlist` global, but that's not recommended)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't understand what you mean because I'm beginner at programming. Can you tell me in more details?

Comment: Probably because word list is defined within your onload  function. Which is out of scope for the actual button. Try attaching it to the window. `window.wordlist=....` instead of var.

Comment: Just copy my answer in the linked question, except with your `wordlist` as well, and it'll work

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa Globals are better avoided when possible, and here, it's possible - better to attach the handler properly with Javascript, so that everything's in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter string is not properly concatenated, should be:

```
x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this.id, '" + wordlist[3] + "')")
```

Though I prefer using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows embedded expressions:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var wordlist = [ "A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD" ];

            for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                x.setAttribute("type", "button");
                x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("onclick", `isTOF(this.id, '${wordlist[3]}')`);
                document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
        }

        function isTOF(v, word) {
            console.log(word);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `${wordlist[3]}`? Isn't that jquery? Can you make it with javascript please?

Comment: @HoseongJeon, no it's not. It is part of the syntax of Template String....Please notice how it is used inside back tick.....

Comment: Oh than is that same with `x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this.id, " + wordlist[3] + ")");`?

Comment: @HoseongJeon, not quite, you have to wrap with quotes, like....`x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this.id, '" + wordlist[3] + "')")`.....to pass that as string....that's why I prefer Template Literals.....thanks.

Comment: Alright. Anyway thank you very much :) You helped me again!

Comment: @HoseongJeon, no problem, glad to help :)